# Run Windows program in Wine as administrator

Tags: 16.04, wine, games, administrator

I am attempting to run the Pokemon Dawn of Darkness game in Ubuntu 16.04 through Wine, but there's a part of the program that Wine does not like (a file called AsyncFile.exe). I can remove that file and the game will still run, but the frame rate will be significantly decreased. I read one page that suggested running it as administrator would fix the problem on Windows, but I can't figure out how to do this on Linux (if it's even possible).

Comment: but what kind of damage?
bc i tried sudo before reading this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as Windows programs are concerned, Wine runs with Windows administrator rights by default when it is started by an user with ordinary permissions (not root permissions). Never run Wine as root using `sudo` because it gives files in your `~/.wine` directory root permissions that can be a security threat to your OS. By doing so you are giving Windows files in the `~/.wine` directory root permissions to make changes to the Ubuntu operating system. If you ran Wine as root, remove your entire `~/.wine` directory. Even if you remove the `~/.wine` directory, running Wine with `sudo` may have done permanent damage to your operating system that can only be repaired by reinstalling the operating system.

Comment: In case the AsyncFile.exe file came from PDoD, [Pokemon: Dawn of Darkness](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16848) has a silver rating at WineHQ application database when running in Wine 1.7, so if you are using Wine 1.6 upgrading to Wine 1.7 or later might help. [How To Install Wine 2.0 Stable On Ubuntu 16.10 & Ubuntu 16.04](http://sourcedigit.com/21863-how-to-install-wine-2-0-stable-on-ubuntu-wine-ppa/)

Comment: it did come from PDoD and I am using version 1.9.14 (2.1 wouldn't even open the game) and I knew running wine as root would be bad so no I didn't do anything that stupid lol. Thanks for the info karel

Comment: Why on earth is wine allowed to be run as root if it causes such catastrophic problems that require a complete re-installation of the operating system?

Comment: @devklick The reason Wine can be run as root is that any user can execute any program with root privileges using the `sudo` command, assuming they have the necessary permissions. This is a fundamental aspect of Linux/Unix systems, where root access is a powerful capability available to administrators. It's up to the user to exercise caution and responsibility when using sudo. It's recommended to run Wine as a regular user to avoid potential issues with file permissions and security. The ability to run it as root is not a recommended or necessary practice for typical usage.

Comment: @karel Sure, I get why a Unix system allows users to run anything as root. But it would be simple for wine to throw up some kind of warning/prompt to say "hey, we notice you're running as root, and this is strongly discouraged", and expect the user to override this warning/prompt. Thinking about the risk/benefit here, if the risk is having to potentially reinstall your entire OS. But I know I'm just whining (or wine-ing) now, so I'll stop. Thanks for your response!